# Is it possible to use Constraint Layout without the Android Studio 2.2 preview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

Is it possible to use Constraint Layout without the Android Studio 2.2 preview or do I have to install the preview in order to test it?

Comment: how do I use it i tried adding the comple comand in the gradel build but it did not show up

Comment: the constraint layout and the new editer

Comment: Getting the artifacts is not straightforward if you are not using Android Studio 2.2+. This was discussed [in this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212128). I have not yet played around with the suggestions. However, by definition, "the new editer" is part of Android Studio, and that requires Android Studio 2.2.

Comment: ohk that makes cence

Comment: Oh! My bad. I thought it said "**with** android studio 2.2" sorry for the confusion